# fnFilter with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, datatables, fnfilter

I got a table with a column called: "Etiquetas" , there i have multiple tag separated by comma (Ex:"Tag, Tag01, Tag02")
And i have a tag search, where i put all tags,and when you click it, this will be added to the actual search (using fnFilter), the values are passed like: '"Tag", "Tag01"' , but if i filter "Tag" , the filter shows me all rows with that word, instead of the one with the exact word. EX: Show rows with "Tag", and "tag", and "Tag01", etc.
I need help for make exact filter, and with multiples values. 
I add a picture to explain this better (i'm bad at explaining things sorry)
[Image with the actual problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4jNR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage find and filter for this. While this wont give you a ranked list, like for example items with most tags matched, it will show only items that have at least a matching tag.

This assumes the tags are given as an array, and that etiquettes is.a string of comma separated tags (it could also be an array, but from what I understood, you mentioned separated by comma, so I assume it's a string).

```js
var items = [
  {title: "1", etiquettes: "tag01"},
  {title: "2", etiquettes: "tag,test"}
];

var tags = ["tag"];

var results = items.filter((item) => {
  // splits the tags in the etiquettes, and tries to find at least a matching one. if so, find will return true to the filter function for the current item
  return item.etiquettes.split(",").find((itemTag) => {
    return tags.indexOf(itemTag) >= 0;
  });
});

console.log(results);
```